# Observable.FromEventPattern on Thumb.DragDelta throws an exception

Tags: wpf, system.reactive

I'm attempting to use Rx for the first time in a WPF project.
I have some Thumbs on a canvas, and I want to use the Observer pattern to handle the events.

This is my code:

```
var dragDelta = Observable.FromEventPattern<DragDeltaEventArgs>(typeof(Thumb), "DragDelta");
```

This is my error:

> "Could not find event 'DragDelta' on type 'System.Windows.Controls.Primitives.Thumb'."

What on earth is going on?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Try to avoid using the reflection-based `FromEventPattern` overloads and use the strongly-typed ones. You won't have these kinds of errors if you do.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think that the event occurs on a specific thumb, you'll need something like:

`var dragDelta = Observable.FromEventPattern<DragDeltaEventArgs>(thumb1, "DragDelta");`